# Compare Columns in 2 Workbooks With multiple entries per cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 workbooks. And I am comparing column entries to verify that all of the entries in one column are represented in the second workbook's column.

I am using the following formula:

```
=IF(OR(TEXT(B2,0)=RIGHT('C:\Users\XXXXXXXXX\Documents\Call Manager Exports\[Doc1.xls]Doc2'!$D$2:$D$1000,10)),"YES","NO")
```

However, I have run into an issue where the workbook I am comparing against, has multiple entries in the same cell. This is of course skewing the data I just cannot figure out how to get the formula to check all of the entries in a cell.

It would be fine if even a single entry of the multiples reported a "NO".

To get an idea.

Both workbooks have phone numbers.

Workbook A has a column with phone numbers and some of the cells have multiple phone numbers in them.

Workbook B has a list of phone numbers and is checking to see that each of it's phone numbers is represented in Workbook A.  IF it is found Workbook A then it reports "yes" if not "no".

Comment: Can you split the phone numbers in Workbook A out into multiple columns? Are they delimited in a uniform way, so you could use Data --> Text to Columns, and put the phone numbers in columns? That may help, since you can then just check if they exist in a range, without having to do some formula that looks for multiple possibilities within a cell.

Comment: @BruceWayne In all cases they are delimited by a new line. All of the cells containing multiple numbers are on new lines within the cell.

Comment: Does [this page](http://support.cyriouswiki.com/Split+Multiple+Lines+of+Text+into+Seperate+Columns) help? Or perhaps [this one](http://www.businessmanagementdaily.com/33958/resolving-text-to-columns-with-line-breaks-in-excel)?

Comment: @BruceWayne I had actually found the second link in my prior searching before asking here. Neither really work (or rather I cannot seem to make them work as I need).